# How to configure com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.Initializer from a configuration file

Tags: java, configuration, cassandra, cluster-computing, datastax

I wanted to know if it's possible to build a `com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.Initializer` from a configuration file as mentioned in the API [java docs](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/).

Are there any existing implementations that parse a file and create the `Cluster.Initializer` or is it expected that we write our own?

Thanks.